# Making NSNull conform to NilLiteralConvertible

Tags: cocoa, swift, protocols, swift-playground, nsnull

I'm trying to make `NSNull` conform to `NilLiteralConvertible`, but I'm running into an enormous amount of frustration:

```
extension NSNull : NilLiteralConvertible{

    required convenience init(nilLiteral: ()){
        self.init()
    }
}
```

First of all, I'm forced to make the `init` a `convenience` one, as I can't add designated initialisers in an extension.

Then, the compiler goes crazy and insists that the init must be made `required` and immediately after complains that `required` initialisers must be added directly to the class and not in an extension. WTF?!

[image: playground]

Anybody knows what's going on and how to make `NSNull` conform to this simple protocol?

I'm testing this in an Xcode playground.

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no reason to conform `NSNull` to `NilLiteralConvertible`.  Although the protocol is public, it's mostly used internally by `NSZone` and the implementation of Optionals in the language (see references in the source [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NilLiteralConvertible)).  You can get the desired behavior your want by just declaring a variable as `Optional<NSNull>`.  The `Optional` enum conforms to `NilLiteralConvertible` for you, as shown in the source of [Optional.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift):

This doesn't work:

```
var null: NSNull

null = NSNull()  // <null>
null = nil // error: nil cannot be assigned to type 'NSNull'
```

But this does:

```
var null: NSNull?

null = NSNull() // <null>
null = nil // nil
```